# How to treat pandas <NA> values in a series/list of numbers to summarize

Tags: pandas

My question focus on the pandas way. Is the behaviour of pandas fixed defined in that situation?

I have a list/series of numbers and want to summarize them. I can do this with `sum()` or with simply `+` operator. The point is that sometimes there is a `<NA>` in such a list. This is OK for me when the result is always `<NA>`.

Of course I could check each element explicit with `if val is pandas.NA`. But I hope there is a better but also save way.

Here is a MWE producing two different results. Using `+` results in a `<NA>` as expected. But `.sum()` simply ignores the `<NA>` in the list and give a concrete number as result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# 1.2.5 and 1.3.2
print(pd.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'VAR': [pd.NA], 'X': [2]})

a = df.VAR + df.X
print(a)  # <NA>

b = df.iloc[0].sum()
print(b)  # 2
```

Comment: that's becasue `Series.sum()` has `skipna=True` by default. If you run `df.iloc[0].sum(skipna=False)` you will get `pd.NA`

Comment: `df.VAR + df.X` goes via a different path instead. it goes via `pd.Series.add` - which doesn't provide a way to control the behavior of `NaN`s

Comment: Correction on above - `pd.Series.add` does provide `fill_value` - i.e. `df.VAR.add(df.X, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `skipna=False` to `sum`, because it's `True` by default:

```
>>> df.iloc[0].sum(skipna=False)
<NA>
```